# Python2&3 : compare str and unicode

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, python-2.x

I'm struggling with a project trying to keep the same code running with Python2.6, Python 2.7 and Python 3.x.

This project uses the [python_2_unicode_compatible class decorator](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/django/utils/encoding.html) in order to store non-unicode values in str type.

I have to test a function *foo* returning a *str* type (not a **unicode** one); the returned value is filled with non-ascii characters.

All I want is to test the value returned by this function against a string of my own, something like :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals  # so that "àbcéfg" will be read u"àbcéfg"
bool_test = (foo() == "àbcéfg")
```

I'm stuck since "àbcéfg" will be considered in Python2 as a **unicode** string, in Python3 as a **str** string.

By example, with Python2, this code raises the following error :

> Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal

Is there a unique way to achieve the comparison, common to Python2 and Python3 ?

I tried several solutions (converting str to bytes, by example), without success.

Any idea to help me ?

Comment: So in Python 2, this must return a bytestring, in Python 3 a Unicode string? That's.. confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing things correctly, but `foo()` doesn't return a Unicode value. It is returning a byte string in Python 2:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return u"àbcéfg".encode('utf8')
... 
>>> foo() == u"àbcéfg"
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
```

Either fix `foo()` or pass it to a function that'll decode the return value if not a Unicode value (here using the [`six` module](http://pythonhosted.org//six/#six.binary_type) to bridge the binary types in Python 2 and 3):

```
import six

def ensure_unicode(value, encoding='utf8'):
    if isinstance(value, six.binary_type):
        return value.decode(encoding)
    return value

bool_test = ensure_unicode(foo()) == "àbcéfg"
```

If `foo()` is meant to return a bytestring in Python 2, and a Unicode string in Python 3, then the above will continue to work but not specifically validate in Python 2 that it is the right type; you could add a separate `isinstance()` test for that:

```
foo_result = foo()
bool_test = isinstance(foo_result, str) and ensure_unicode(foo_result) == "àbcéfg"
```

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, I'm not allowed to use any extern library. The value returned by foo() is a **str** ( -> type(foo()) returns str ) : I forgot to say that the class I'm working on is modified by the *python_2_unicode_compatible* class decorator.